# Consumer of Android library module having to add classpath dependencies

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, kotlin-dokka

I have an Android app (`app` module) and an Android library module (`lib` module), each being a separate Android Studio project, but the app project added `lib` in as a module dependency in its project.

The `lib` uses JetBrain's [Dokka](https://github.com/Kotlin/dokka#android) to generate HTML documentation, and it needs the Dokka Android Gradle plugin, which is defined in *its own project's top-level `build.gradle`*:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath "org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-android-gradle-plugin:0.9.18"
    }
}
```

And in the `lib` module's `build.gradle` I had to add the following

```
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.dokka-android'

android {
    // ...
    dokka { /* my Dokka config */ }
}
```

So right now the `lib` project works and builds fine and I'm able to generate documentation HTMLs using Dokka.

However, my app project's Gradle sync now fails because it says "Plugin with id  org.jetbrains.dokka-android not found". If I add the `classpath "org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-android-gradle-plugin:0.9.18"` to my app project's top-level `build.gradle` then it works fine.

My question is, how do I tell the main (app) project that the classpath dependency for Dokka has already been declared in the `lib` module's top-level `build.gradle`?  Or is there a way to specify this dependency for *just* the `lib` module? I also think it's weird if I have multiple apps using my `lib` module and they would need to add this classpath dependency to be able to build their apps.

Much thanks.

Comment: How do you import lib? You shouldn't build doc (and then the mokka requirement) if you are working on the app and not the lib.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti My `lib` module is imported by specifying the path to it in `settings.gradle` then I include it as a dependency in my `app` level `build.gradle`. The thing is that the `apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.dokka-android'` part in the `lib`'s `build.gradle` is complaining that it couldn't find the plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add this part in your `lib/build.gradle` removing from the top-level file.

```
buildscript {
    //
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-android-gradle-plugin:0.9.18'
    }
}
```

It happens because you are importing this lib as an external module and you are running some tasks (for example a `build` task) in the `lib` module.
You can avoid it:

- import your lib as an aar or a maven dependency (best option is to publish in a private maven repo)
- just run tasks related to the app.

Comment: Thanks, this was it! I wasn't aware that we can have `buildscript` blocks in module-level `build.gradle` files.